# How to get the proper date format?

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format

I am getting the system time like this (`Thu Nov 14 14:38:16 IST 2013`) and I have to convert it to (`MM/dd/yy`) .I tried and getting a error while parsing here is my code ,

```
String stime = calendar.getTime().toString();         
System.out.println("  time is " +stime);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");          
Date dateCC = formatter.parse(stime);
calendar.setTime(dateCC);
```

The error is NullpointerException, but i want the date in this format (`MM/dd/yy`). Could please tell me what mistake i did?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Post the StackTrace of the NPE

Comment: Where are you getting NPE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date` as such has no format. It just represents the time since the *epoch (00:00:00 GMT on January 1, 1970)*. Therefore, it doesn't make sense in saying that you want to get the `Date` in a specific format. You can, however, get a formatted String representation of it though by using a `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");          
String dateString = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a SimpleDateFormat instance with the format you want and then use it to format a Date or Time object like this :

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
 System.out.println(sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
```

Refer this [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) when need help with the formats allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();        
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");          
    String stime = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
    System.out.println(stime);
    Date dateCC = formatter.parse(stime);
    calendar.setTime(dateCC);
    System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

In Joda-Time 2.3 in Java 7.

```java
org.joda.time.DateTimeZone losAngelesTimeZone = org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles");
org.joda.time.DateTime nowInCalifornia = new org.joda.time.DateTime( losAngelesTimeZone );
org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter formatter = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yy");
String nowInCaliforniaAsString = formatter.print( nowInCalifornia );
System.out.println( "nowInCaliforniaAsString: " + nowInCaliforniaAsString );
```